# How to convert "2003-11-05T16:35:30Z" to "11/5/2013 " in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion

I am having a problem while converting

```
 2003-11-05T16:35:30Z  to "11/5/2013"
```

I tried below

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("2003-11-05T16:35:30Z", "dd/MM/yyyy", null)
```

but I am not getting the value I expect.

Comment: `2003-11-05T16:35:30Z` is datetime value or string

Comment: `2003-11-05T16:35:30Z` is a `string` or a `datetime` object?

Comment: 2003-11-05T16:35:30Z is a string

Comment: `DateTime.Parse("2003-11-05T16:35:30Z").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
DateTimeOffset.Parse("2003-11-05T16:35:30Z").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

What you're doing is parsing the data as if it were in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` - instead, you want to parse it as the universal format it is, and then convert it to a string with your format string.

`DateTime.Parse` will take a string and return a date time. To get a string back out, you simply use the `ToString` method.

Comment: exactly...it is UTC Datetime

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
string myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2003-11-05T16:35:30Z", 
                               "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ",null).ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

When parsing you specify the format that you are parsing from, then you format the `DateTime` value using the new format:

```
string reformatted =
  DateTime.ParseExact("2003-11-05T16:35:30Z", "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'", null)
  .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```